# Most efficient way to replace empty values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there a better way of doing this PHP code? What I'm doing is looping through the array and replacing the "title" field if it's blank.

```
if($result)
{
    $count = 0; 

    foreach($result as $result_row)
    {
        if( !$result_row["title"] )
        {
            $result[$count]["title"] = "untitled";
        }

        $count++;
    }
}
```

Where *$result* is an array with data like this:

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [title] => sdsdsdsd
                        [body] => ssdsd
                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                        [title] => sdssdsfds
                        [body] => sdsdsd
                )


)
```

I'm not an experienced PHP developer, but I guess that the way I've proposed above isn't the most efficient?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say this is probably plenty fast unless you have a bazillion rows (in which case you'd probably have some other problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing in a little more to @Luke's answer...

```
if($result) {
  foreach($result as &$result_row) {  // <--- Add & here
    if($result_row['title'] == '') {
      $result_row['title'] = 'untitled';
    }
  }
}
```

The key is the & before $result_row in the foreach statement.  This make it a foreach by reference.  Without that, the value of $result_row is a copy, not the original.  Your loop will finish and do all the processing but it won't be kept.

The only way to get more efficient is to look at where the data comes from.  If you're retrieving it from a database, could you potentially save each record with an "untitled" value as the default so you don't need to go back and put in the value later?

Comment: `||=` is still not valid. ;) And assigning the value as reference won't make it more efficient really.

Comment: Just saw Luke's comments so I replaced the ||= operator.  Explains why I couldn't find it for PHP, no such animal.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($result) {
    foreach($result as $index=>$result_row) {
        if( !$result_row["title"] ) {
            $result[$index]["title"] = "untitled";
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need to count it. It's efficient.

Comment: What is the `if($result)` doing in there? What if `$result` is a string? I could understand `if (is_array($result))` but this doesn't compute..

Comment: yes, is_array would be better.  That was just a copy and paste from his original and i didn't think of changing that part.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($result)
{
    foreach($result as &$result_row)
    {
        if(!$result_row['title'])
        {
            $result_row['title'] = 'untitled';
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may want to use something other than a boolean cast to check the existence of a title in case some young punk director releases a movie called `0`.

You could do something like `if (trim($result_row['title']) == '')`

Comment: +1 for correct reference approach. Though `trim == ''` won't help against `0`. For PHP `'0' == ''`. You would need to `===`.

Comment: @nikic: `'0' == ''` returns `false` while `0 == ''` returns `true`. `$result_row['title']` will be a string so this will work fine.

Comment: Wow, seems like PHPs type juggling finally did drive me crazy... Always thought that would yield true.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative could be `json_encode` + `str_replace()` and then `json_decode()`:

```
$data = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        'title' => '',
        'body' => 'empty',
    ),

    1 => array
    (
        'title' => 'set',
        'body' => 'not-empty',
    ),
);

$data = json_encode($data); // [{"title":"","body":"empty"},{"title":"set","body":"not-empty"}]
$data = json_decode(str_replace('"title":""', '"title":"untitled"', $data), true);
```

As a one-liner:

```
$data = json_decode(str_replace('"title":""', '"title":"untitled"', json_encode($data)), true);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => untitled
            [body] => empty
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => set
            [body] => not-empty
        )
)
```

I'm not sure if this is more efficient (I doubt it, but you can benchmark it), but at least it's a different way of doing the same and should work fine - you have to care about multi-dimensional arrays if you use the `title` index elsewhere thought.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php):

```
<?php 
$myArr = array (array("title" => "sdsdsdsd", "body" => "ssdsd"), 
              array("title" => "", "body" => "sdsdsd")  );
array_walk_recursive($myArr, "convertTitle");
var_dump($myArr);

function convertTitle(&$item, $key) {
  if ($key=='title' && empty($item)) {$item = "untitled";}
}
?>
```

Comment: Interesting but overhead makes this method many times slower than simple foreach.

Comment: This could probably spark another question, but what overhead? or are you referring to the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sweet and short, try this one

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'title' => 'foo',
        'body' => 'bar'
    ),
    array(
        'body' => 'baz'
    ),
    array(
        'body' => 'qux'
    ),
);

foreach($result as &$entry) if (empty($entry['title'])) {
    $entry['title'] = 'no val';
}

var_dump($records);
```

the `empty()` will do the job, see the doc http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php